# Disable popup button on ActionBar that has settings menu item

Tags: java, android

My action bar has this button on the top right :

[image]

And when I click it, it gives me a settings menu item which does nothing on click:

[image]

I would like to disable the button in the first picture (looks like an ellipsis but rotated) from my ActionBar.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default overflow menu that is set by the SDK when you create a new Android project.

To disable the menu you just have to remove the code that adds it. You should have a method `onCreateOptionsMenu()` overridden somewhere in your Activity, which you can remove.

Answer (score 0):

selects a contextual menu item

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
}
```

more info here - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu